# How to change monitor number?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, xmonad

I recently installed xmonad on Ubuntu 12.04.3 Precise Pangolin and the default keybindings are mod-w to switch to monitor 0 and mod-e to switch to monitor 1.

Unfortunately my monitors are positioned in the opposite order on my desk, with the left monitor being 1 and the middle monitor being 0. Changing cables won't work since the left monitor will not preserve its maximum resolution of 1920x1200 on VGA (I only have 1 HDMI port and it's using it), even though I tried to install that new mode several times with xrandr --addmode etc.

While I could technically physically swap the position of the monitors on my desk, or swap the xmonad keybindings, I'd love to know if there's a way to swap monitor numbers within X to achieve a similar effect. I haven't managed to find anything on Google, so I'm hoping folks here might know. Thank you!

Comment: I'm currently already using xrandr as follows: xrandr --output HDMI2 --auto --left-of VGA1 . Is the idea that I can shuffle them around until they're in the right order?

Comment: Ah brilliant, seems like this worked: xrandr --auto --output HDMI2 --primary --left-of VGA1

Comment: Care to turn that into an answer maybe? I'll confirm.

Comment: Close voters: This question has a good answer. I see no reason for closing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With xrandr, use the options `--right-of` , `--left-of` and `--primary` as needed.

Once you find the options you desire, call xrandr (with the otpins you desire) at log in.

From your comment:

```
xrandr --auto --output HDMI2 --primary --left-of VGA1
```

See http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/use-xrandr-to-set-a-screen-resolution/ and man xrandr for details.